# std::sort vector of struct invalid operator<

Tags: c++, sorting, strict-weak-ordering

I have problem with *strict weak ordering* in the compare function in std::sort. I can't see why this would fail.

I have some nested structs:

```
struct date{
    int day = 1;
    int month = 1;
    int year = 2017;
};    
struct hhmmss{
    int hours = 1;
    int minutes = 1;
    int seconds = 1;
};    
struct dateAndTime {
   date d;
   hhmmss t;
};    
struct Trade
{
   /*
   other unrelevant data
   */
   dateAndTime timeClosed;
};
```

In my code, at some point I have a populated `std::vector<Trade>` which I want to sort.

My sort function:

```
void sortTradesByDate(std::vector<Trade>& trades){
   std::sort(trades.begin(), trades.end(), compareDateAndTime);
}
```

My comparison function:

```
bool compareDateAndTime(const Trade& t1, const Trade& t2){
   if (t1.timeClosed.d.year < t2.timeClosed.d.year)
      return true;
   else if (t1.timeClosed.d.month < t2.timeClosed.d.month)
      return true;
   else if (t1.timeClosed.d.day < t2.timeClosed.d.day)
      return true;
   else if (t1.timeClosed.t.hours < t2.timeClosed.t.hours)
      return true;
   else if (t1.timeClosed.t.minutes < t2.timeClosed.t.minutes)
      return true;
   else if (t1.timeClosed.t.seconds < t2.timeClosed.t.seconds)
      return true;
   return false;      
}
```

When running the function, and debuging, my first item passed to `compareDateAndTime()` passes after returning true on one of the statements (months).
The next item returns true at hours comparison, but then I get a "Debug Assertion Failed!" with "Expression: invalid operator<".

Doing some googling, this has to do with *strict weak ordering*. But why does this fail when comparing int variables?

Comment: It fails because the comparator doesn't implement a strict weak ordering comparison. You could easily check that with some unit tests.

Comment: The problem is that there are objects for which you have both `d1 < d2` and `d2 < d1`.

Comment: But why would it sometimes fail, and sometimes pass? Wouldn't it always fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comparison function isn't implementing strict weak ordering

Consider this scenario:

- `t1`: year=2017, month=2
- `t2`: year=2016, month=5

`compareDateAndTime(t1, t2)` would return `true`.

You should proceed to compare `month` if and only if `year` is the same.

```
if (t1.timeClosed.d.year < t2.timeClosed.d.year)
    return true;
if (t1.timeClosed.d.year > t2.timeClosed.d.year)
    return false;
if (t1.timeClosed.d.month < t2.timeClosed.d.month)
    return true;
if (t1.timeClosed.d.month > t2.timeClosed.d.month)
    return false;
```

... and so forth ...

Comment: Worked like a charm and made sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A nice way to leverage the Standard Library:

```
return std::tie(t1.timeClosed.d.year, t1.timeClosed.d.month) < std::tie(t2.timeClosed.d.year, t2.timeClosed.d.month);
```

You can add the missing members inside the std::tie's (it's a variadic template). This uses std::tuple's operator<, which is defined to do what you expect.